# paginado en react para sub elementos de cada elemento de una lista

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Intento hacer un paginado para ver sub-elementos de cada elemento de una lista, en este caso es una lista de equipos de futbol la cual la obtengo de un fetch con la funcion searchTeamPlayers(), y deseo que al escoger cualquier equipo se muestre el paginado de los jugadores de a 10 por pagina, pero al actualizar la pagina web no se muestran, le doy click en el boton next y se comienza a ver los jugadores de a 10, pero al seleccionar otro equipo no actualiza los jugadores si no que quedan los del primer equipo, supongo que se debe utilizar un useEffect para que escuche el cambio de equipo pero no se como realizar la logica o la funcion de tal manera que al actualizar la pagina web salga de una vez la lista de jugadores de el primer equipo paginada de a 10, y al seleccionar otro equipo salga la lista de jugadores paginada del equipo seleccionado. Agradezco la ayuda.

```
        const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10;

      function App() {
        
      const [league, setLeague] = useState([]);
      const [idTeam, setIdTeam] = useState(33);
      const [teamPlayers, setTeamPlayers] = useState([]);
      const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

      
      const [playersForPage, setPlayersForPage] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        getSoccerLeagues()
          .then((data) => setLeague(data.response))
          .catch(handleError);
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        searchTeamPlayers(idTeam)
          .then((data) => setTeamPlayers(data))
          .catch(handleError);
      }, [idTeam]);
      
      function handleDetails(lea){
        const id = lea.team.id;
        setIdTeam(id);
      }

      function nextHandler() {
        const totalItems = teamPlayers.length;
        const nextPage = currentPage + 1;
        const firstIndex = nextPage * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        if (firstIndex >= totalItems) return;
        setPlayersForPage([...teamPlayers].splice(firstIndex, ITEMS_PER_PAGE));
        setCurrentPage(nextPage);
      }

      function prevHandler() {
        const prevPage = currentPage - 1;
        if (prevPage < 0) return;
        const firstIndex = prevPage * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        setPlayersForPage([...teamPlayers].splice(firstIndex, ITEMS_PER_PAGE));
        setCurrentPage(prevPage);
      }
      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <div className='List'>
            <h2 className='TitleTeamsList'>Equipos</h2>
            <ul>
              {league.map((lea) => (
                <li key={lea.team.id} onClick={() => handleDetails(lea)}>{lea.team.name}</li>
              ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <Players currentPage={currentPage} players={playersForPage} nextHandler={nextHandler} prevHandler={prevHandler}></Players>
        </div>
        );
      }
      export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el problema del paginado para subelementos de cada elemento de una lista con este código:

```
    useEffect(() => {
       const players = [...teamPlayers].splice(0, ITEMS_PER_PAGE);
       setPlayersForPage(players)
      }, [teamPlayers]);
```